# DbUpdateException while trying to update existing record

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
 using (var ctx = new Model.VMcontext())
        {
            List<Model.Process> Pr = new List<Model.Process>();
            Model.Process pp;
            foreach (RemoteProcess item in queueItem.rp)
            {
                pp = new Model.Process(item.ProcName, item.Procstatus, item.Timestamp, item.mcName);
                Pr.Add(pp);
            }


            VM vm = new VM(queueItem.VM_Hostname, queueItem.Disks ,queueItem.VMstatus, Pr);


            // compare vm object ref with current db objects 
            // If VM not present, insert VM

            VM DBvm = ctx.VirtualMachines.Find(vm.VM_Hostname);
            if (DBvm==null)
            {
                ctx.VirtualMachines.Add(vm);

            }
            // else VM exists so, update it [ERROR OCCURS HERE]
            else
            {

                //DBvm = vm;
                //ctx.Entry(vm).State = EntityState.Modified;   I tried various update methods too
                DBvm.disks = vm.disks;
                DBvm.Processes = vm.Processes;
                DBvm.VMstatus = vm.VMstatus;

            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

When i update an existing record, an exception is thrown. I looked up other answers here but none seem to help.

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Where am in going wrong ??

**edit**
As suggested,  looked into the inner exceptions and it says that i am trying to insert a duplicate value 'C:' into the disk table. But i am not inserting any data, im just finding the existing record and updating it. Im not sure how im getting a Primary key duplicate error*

**EDIT 2**

```
public class VM
{
    public VM(string host,List<Disk>d ,int stat,List<Process> procs)
    {
        VM_Hostname = host;
        disks = d;
        VMstatus = stat;
        Processes = procs;
    }

    public VM() { }

    [Key]
    public string VM_Hostname { get; set; }
    public int VMstatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Model.Process> Processes { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Disk> disks { get; set; }
}

public class Process
{
    public Process(string pname,int stat,DateTime d, string vm )
    {
        ProcessName = pname;
        status = stat;
        date = d;
        VM_hostname = vm;
    }

    public Process() { }

    [Key]
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

    public string VM_hostname { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VM_hostname")]
    public virtual Model.VM vm { get; set; }
}

 public class Disk
{

    [Key]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double freeSpace { get; set; }
    public double freePercent { get; set; }
    public double totalSpace { get; set; }
    public double used { get; set; }
    public string VM_hostname { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VM_hostname")]
    public virtual Model.VM vm { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Go to the inner exception and see what the message is.. :)

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Disks'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Disks'. The duplicate key value is (C:\).

Comment: @Rinktacular  But im not inserting a duplicate record, Im just updating it ?

Comment: Which column is the primary key?  You are not modifying it are you?

Comment: @BrandonKramer Disk name is the primary key

Comment: Are `DBvm.Processes` and `DBvm.VMstatus` a list of related entities?

Comment: @BrandonKramer Ill put up my POCO classes. have  a look

Comment: @BrandonKramer Please check my classes . is there anything wrong thats casuing the exception ?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you are trying to overwrite the list of `disks` and `Processes` with a list of entities that are not attached to the context.  So it is trying to create new disks instead of updating the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, your issue is that you are using a list of `Disk` and `Process` objects that were created before the current context was created.  Therefore, the context does not know about them, and when you replace the list of `Disk` and `Process` objects on your `VM` entity, the context assumes they are all new items, and tries to add them to the database.  But since they are not new items, there are primary key conflicts that cause the exception you are seeing.

To solve your issue, you need to attach the `Disk` and `Process` objects to your context before saving them.

E.g:

```
VM DBvm = ctx.VirtualMachines.Find(vm.VM_Hostname);
if (DBvm==null)
{
    ctx.VirtualMachines.Add(vm);

}
// else VM exists so, update it [ERROR OCCURS HERE]
else
{

    //DBvm = vm;
    //ctx.Entry(vm).State = EntityState.Modified;   I tried various update methods too
    foreach (var disk in vm.disks)
    {
        //Only attach if the entity already exists, otherwise just let it get added.
        if (ctx.Disks.Find(disk) != null) 
        {
            ctx.Disks.Attach(disk);
            ctx.Entry(disk).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    foreach (var process in vm.Processes)
    {
        if (ctx.Processes.Find(process) != null)
        {
            ctx.Processes.Attach(process);
            ctx.Entry(process).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
    DBvm.disks = vm.disks;
    DBvm.Processes = vm.Processes;
    DBvm.VMstatus = vm.VMstatus;

}
```

The addition of the loops to attach your entities should solve the exception, since it tells the context about these objects, and setting their State to modified means they are not new, and should be updated, rather than inserted.